# How can I sort one table by a column in another in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting

Say I have a table named `items`:

```
id      int(11)
...
tag     int(11)
```

And another table named `tags`:

```
id      int(11)
name    varchar(255)
```

The `tag` column in `items` is an index into the `tags` table. How can I select some rows from the `items` table and sort the results by the `name` column in `tags`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT items.id, items.tag, tags.name FROM items LEFT JOIN tags on items.id = tags.id ORDER BY tags.name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join the tables but you do not have to select the name column from the tags table.

```
 select a.id, a.tag
 from items a join tags b on a.tag = b.id
 order by b.name
```

This way you are selecting items sorted by the tag name.